# Вывести документ Word формата html через WebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

Как через элемент `WebBrowser` вывести текстовый документ Word, сохраненный в формате HTML?

Вот мой код:

```
string path = Application.StartupPath + @"\info\html\page.html";
webBrowser1.Navigate(path);
```

Дело в том, что при запуске формы с `WebBrowser`'ом выводится ненужное мне диалоговое окно выбора действий с текстовым файлом (`Сохранить`, `Открыть`) и в самом элементе отображается сообщение `Не найден путь к файлу. Введите адрес повторно`.

Comment: у вас есть >>текстовый документ Word<< который находится >>в формате html<< ? Если верить вашим словам, у вас есть легковой автомобиль, который находится в состоянии камаза. Так что там у вас в действительности? Легковой автомобиль или камаз? Какое реальное расширение, и в каком формате исходный документ, который вы выводите?

Comment: Текстовый файл сохранен как веб-документ именно в формате html

Comment: Возможно, вы забыли указать протокол? Попробуйте делать такой URI: file:///C:/test.html

Comment: В вашем случае, это будет примерно так: string path = "file:///"+Application.StartupPath + "/info/html/page.html";

Comment: @АлексСкай Можете отредактировать вопрос, чтобы было ясно, что у вас за формат документа?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, исправил. По-моему, должно быть понятно.

Comment: @АлексСкай Ну хорошо, а почему ваш код вас не устаивает?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, дело в том, что при запуске формы с WebBrowser'ом выводится ненужное мне диалоговое окно выбора действий с текстовым файлом (Сохранить, Открыть) и в самом элементе отображается сообщение "Не найден путь к файлу. Введите адрес повторно"

Comment: @АлексСкай, вы пробовали добавлять протокол?

Comment: Сейчас проделал все шаги у себя, всё работает с вашим кодом. Проверьте тип вашего файла ещё раз. А лучше, выложите его содержимое (достаточно нескольких сотен байт начала файла), чтобы мы могли его посмотреть.

Comment: Точно! Все работает. Обнаружил ошибку в расширении (html вместо htm). Спасибо Вам за помощь